# Optimizing the Nested dictionary in python problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If one receiver has the most in each category you have to return his name. If there is no receiver with the most values in all categories you should return 'None of them'.

```
receivers = ({'abdul': {'a': 1800, 'b': 18, 'c': 117},
              'ahmed' :  {'a': 1700, 'b': 17, 'c': 116},
              'rehman' : {'a': 1750,'b': 16, 'c': 113}})
     
def triple_crown(receivers):
aa= [j['a'] for i,j in l.items()]
bb= [j['b'] for i,j in l.items()]
cc= [j['c'] for i,j in l.items()]
p = ['abdul', 'ahmed', 'rehman']
for i,j in enumerate(list(zip(aa,bb,cc))):
    x,y,z=j
    if x==max(aa) and aa.count(x)==1:
        if y==max(bb) and bb.count(y)==1:
            if z==max(cc) and cc.count(z)==1:
                return p[i]
else:
    return 'None of them'
```

the output should be 'abdul' since he has more a,b and c value than his counterparts

I defined the function this way but i guess there should be a better way to do this as this very bad solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

First, traverse `receivers` and the inner dicts to create a dictionary `max_dct` from the max values across all inner dicts

Then, check if the `max_dct` exists in `receivers`, if it does, find the key it corresponds to, if not print "None"

```
max_dct = {}
for name, dct in receivers.items():
    for k,v in dct.items():
        max_dct[k] = max_dct[k] if k in max_dct and max_dct[k] > v else v

out = None
for name, dct in receivers.items():
    common_vals = set(max_dct.values()) & set(dct.values())
    if common_vals:
        if len(common_vals) == len(max_dct):
            out = name
        break
        
out = out if out is not None else 'None of them'
print(out)
```

Output:

```
abdul
```

Comment: Excellent solution! there is however one problem that it should return none of them for the case where two players have same score. but instead it counts it as best

Comment: receivers = ({'abdul': {'a': 1800, 'b': 16, 'c': 117},
              'ahmed' :  {'a': 1700, 'b': 17, 'c': 116},
              'rehman' : {'a': 1800,'b': 16, 'c': 200}}) for eg for this dic the output is 'rehman' but it should be none of them. even for your updated one

Comment: receivers = ({'abdul': {'a': 1800, 'b': 16, 'c': 110},
              'ahmed' :  {'a': 1700, 'b': 15, 'c': 112},
              'rehman' : {'a': 1800,'b': 16, 'c': 113}}) yes you are right but when i changed the values for this one for eg it would output 'rehman' instead of none of them

Comment: @abdulrehman so the only case where you throw up a name is when all three values are greater?

Comment: yes, all values should be greater. I get your solution iterates through the inner dict and saves the max values and then compares it with the dict to see if there exists a match between max dict and receivers. but incase of equal values . i couldnt understand how to counter it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241411/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-and-enke).